# Upload video on twitter using ios5 + iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, ios5

Hiii,

I have uploaded image and status message successfully using TWTweetComposeViewController .. but i am not able to find anything to upload video using same class ..

Please suggest me to if you have any link or guideline .

Thanks in advance ..
    abhishek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter Does not host any videos.go through this [support.twitter.com](https://support.twitter.com/articles/75603-how-to-post-videos-on-twitter)

Answer (score 2):

Twitter doesn't support videos natively. You would have to upload the video manually to a third-party service (such as YouTube or Vimeo or Twitvid or yfrog or …) and then share the link on Twitter.

Comment: Hi @Ole Begemann
I want to share Video link in twitter ,
How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **TWRequest** class with

```
 - (void)addMultiPartData:(NSData *)data withName:(NSString *)name type:(NSString *)type
```

You need to include following headers:

```
#import "Twitter/Twitter.h"
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
```

I am not sure if uploading video is possible.

More on using TWRequest
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/posting-images-using-twrequest

Comment: this is only for image and text Tweet.. not for video!!